# Gatsby Deploy With GH-Pages and --Path-Pefix Is Broken

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, github-pages

I asked [this question](https://spectrum.chat/gatsby-js/general/gh-pages-deploy-not-working%7E0ddc4579-a350-4f31-bc74-2120b7fd8a51) in the spectrum chat, but I guess that community is deprecated.

I am basically trying to deploy my Gatsby site to gh-pages, but it's not working properly.

The source code is located here: https://jimlynchcodes.github.io/Evaluates2-Site/

I am building the app like this:

```
gatsby build --path-prefix="Evaluates2-Site"
```

and deploying like this:

```
gh-pages -d -public
```

The [deployed site](https://jimlynchcodes.github.io/Evaluates2-Site/) looks very broken though and has many errors in the console...

How can I deploy this site cleanly so that it woks properly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/path-prefix/#add-to-gatsby-configjs).

```
// gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: `/Evaluates2-Site`,
}
```

then building

```
gatsby build --prefix-paths
```